# I am unable render component with click a button

Tags: reactjs

When click a button, it should render an element, but it does not work. If I click, nothing happens, nor does it trigger any error.
I'm using material UI

component content is a form

```js
function handleBoxRegister(){
    return (
      <div>test</div>
    )
  }
```

```
<Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.buttonRegister}
          onClick={handleBoxRegister}
        >
          <AddIcon>
          </AddIcon>
          Registrar paciente
        </Button>
```

Comment: This wont work. You cant `return` a component from a function and expect that to be in added into the render tree.

Comment: Tell me more about what you are trying to do, Are you trying to show a component after the form is submitted? If you add more info I can help you with a better answer.

Comment: It has a div in the middle of the screen and a sidebar with several buttons, one of which is registration. Then when the user clicks on it, a form should appear in the middle of the screen

Comment: Yes, but I didn't understand very well, now it made perfect sense, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> It has a div in the middle of the screen and a sidebar with several buttons, one of which is registration. Then when the user clicks on it, a form should appear in the middle of the screen.

This is where state comes in, to make the form appear/disappear from the view you should can store the data (state) in a `boolean` variable and check if that is `true` or `false` then in the render show it or hide it as per the value of the variable.

Below we are using the `&&` operator, which will render the component after it only if the first value is `true`.

**For example:**

```
function exmapleView (props) {
  const [isRegisterShown, setIsRegisterShown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.buttonRegister}
          onClick={() => setIsRegisterShown(true)}>
      </Sidebar>
      {isRegisterShown && <div>// Add the Register Form</div>}
      // Add Other Components here
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Consider marking it as the accepted answer and upvoting. So we can help others with the same question on StackOverflow